# Dreamweaver CS5 with php 5.3 namespace tag

Tags: php, dreamweaver

Dreamweaver has been my favourite IDE for programming PHP for a while.
However we have recently updated our servers to work with php 5.3.x

Now everytime I use php 5.3 specific tags like namespace dreamweaver suggests that there is a syntax error.

I would like to be able to add the namespace as a valid tag or install a plugin which does that for me. If that can't be done it would be best if I could just disable the checking for errors.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dreamweaver CS5.5 Dynamic Code HInting PHP support is updated to PHP 5.3

Answer (score 1):

Dreamweaver CS5 PHP support is limited to PHP 5.2 (based on a couple of Google searches), and the syntax checker is not extensible, so no extension would be able to make that go away. I've seen in a couple of places that you can turn off the error checking by turning off the PHP related code hints (Edit [Dreamweaver on Mac] -> Preferences -> Code Hints), but I've not tried that. Of course, if that works, then you'll get no code hints for variables and functions defined in your code, so not sure that will be a good trade off. On the other hand, Dreamweaver does report that code hinting may not work until syntax errors are corrected.